# Oracle BI (OBIEE) - Wildcard search for numeric values only

Tags: obiee

I need to set up  a query that returns only the values that would match a pattern {Any character & digit}
I've tried setting up a filter criteria to ' %_
[0-9] but it doesn't work...I want to exclude any results that have two letters as the first two characters of a value. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the presentation column, you can use the [OBIEE - Evaluate - Embedded DB Functions](http://gerardnico.com/wiki/dat/obiee/evaluate) in a formula.

For example (not the exact regex you are looking for but you get the point):
[image]

This link contains the same image/example I uploaded, as well as a few others: http://gerardnico.com/wiki/dat/obiee/regexp_evaluate

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark, this is very helpful, unfortunately I don't have reputation to vote  your answer up

Comment: If it answers your question then you can always accept as answer. If not, you should comment why so myself or someone else can add a new answer or edit this answer to help you. You are welcome though!